# Cannot get ADC value and put it into a array STM32F103C8T6

Tags: arm, embedded, stm32, adc

I try to put ADC value into a 1d array and transmit it to PC.
But it is not work. I using **HAL_ADC_GetValue()** to read data from *chanel0* of *ADC1*.
Here is my code:

```
// maxziedata = 2048.
uint8_t DATA_ALL[MAXSIZEDATA];

void ReadAll(){
memset(DATA_ALL, 0, sizeof(DATA_ALL));
delay_us(timeDelay);
int count =-1;
//Read 32 Row
for(int row=0; row<32; row++){
    SelectRow(row);                             //Read 32 Row   
    for(int col=0; col<32; col++){
        SelectCol(col);                           //Read 32 Column
        ++count;
        HAL_ADC_Start(&hadc1);
        HAL_ADC_PollForConversion(&hadc1,50);
        HAL_IS_BIT_SET(HAL_ADC_GetState(&hadc1), HAL_ADC_STATE_REG_EOC);
        
        delay_us(10);
        uint16_t data = HAL_ADC_GetValue(&hadc1); // Data is alway equal 0      
        // if data = n, PC will received data.  
        DATA_ALL[count*2] = data & 0xff;
        DATA_ALL[count*2+1] = (data >> 8) & 0xff;
        
        HAL_ADC_Stop(&hadc1);
    }
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB,EN_COL_1_Pin,GPIO_PIN_SET);
  }
   HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA,EN_ROW_1_Pin,GPIO_PIN_SET);
}
```

If I fake data `uint16_t data = HAL_ADC_GetValue(&hadc1);` change to `uint16_t data = count`, PC will receive data.
When I transmit **only one** value of array, PC will be received data.

```
void ReadOne(int row, int col){
    memset(SEND_DATA, 0, sizeof(SEND_DATA));
    HAL_ADC_Start(&hadc1);
    SelectRow(row);
    SelectCol(col);
    HAL_ADC_Start(&hadc1);
    delay_us(100);
    HAL_ADC_PollForConversion(&hadc1,1);
    uint16_t avg = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<samplingTimes; i++){
        avg += HAL_ADC_GetValue(&hadc1);
    }
    SEND_DATA[(row*32+col)*2] = avg/samplingTimes & 0xff;
    SEND_DATA[((row*32+col)*2)+1] = (avg/samplingTimes >> 8) & 0xff;

    HAL_ADC_Stop(&hadc1);
    delay_us(100);
}
```

Here is my config ADC:
[image: Here is my config ADC]

The main problem is **HAL_ADC_GetValue()** cannot put data into array after step of loop

Comment: Try to isolate the problem further, by making small changes and clean-ups to the working version of your code, and try to find out if it really has something to do with your ADC/STM32/hardware or if it is a software issue. - There are many things that can go wrong. I'd try to remove the PC communication part (timing issue?) and buffering/array/loop part, and make a separate ADC read function first, and test it until it works reliably. Then you can start to store/process/send the values, and test/debug that part step by step. And maybe optimize things later on with DMA, better config etc.

Comment: Check the return values of `HAL_ADC_Start()` and `HAL_ADC_PollForConversion()`.

Comment: Regardless of what is wrong here, you might consider using DMA to load `DATA_ALL` directly (making it a `uint16_t` also).  If the byte ordering is critical, you can fix that in the transmission to the PC or at the PC itself.